# Understanding multilevel feedback queue scheduling

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I'm trying to understand multilevel feedback queue scheduling and I came across the following example from William Stallings Operating Systems Internal and Principles Design (7th ed).

I got this process:

[image]

And the result in the book is this:
[image]

I believe I'm doing the first steps wright but when I get to process `E` CPU time my next process is `B` not `D` as in the book example.

I can't understand if there are `n` `RQ` and after each time a process get's CPU time it is demoted to a lower priority time `RQ` or if, for example, process `A` is in `RQ1` and there are no process at the çower `RQ`, the process is promoted to that ready queue (this is how I am doing).

Can someone explain me the process how, at the above example, after `E` is processed, `D` gets CPU time and them `E` (and not `B`) is served?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multilevel feedback algortihm selects always the first job of the lowest queue (i.e., the queue with the highest priority) that is not empty.

When job E leaves RQ1 (time 9), job D is in queue RT2 but job B in RT3. Thus, B is executed. Please consider the modified figure, where the red numbers give the queue in which the job is executed.
[image: run queues]

As you can see, job B has already left RT2 at time 9 (more preceisly, it leaves RT2 at time 6), whereas job D has just entered.

Comment: I know that it's an old answer. But still can someone tell me why does A execute at time 4 ? After time 3, B is demoted to second queue right, so it should be executed first because A would be in 3rd queue after time 2

Comment: @Zephyr Did you get the answer to your question? I think there is a problem in numbering and that A would still be in queue 1 because there's no other process in the system. Let me know if I'm wrong.